# Change Candle color based on Stochastic values

Tags: highcharts

On a custom candle chart, we need to edit the candle color based on the values from a stochastic series linked to that candle chart.

Looking for a way to catch the Kvalue and Dvalue and implement some colors based on the values.  Something similar to the below:

```js
    if (Kvalue < Dvalue && Kvalue < 80) {
        color = 'red';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute these colors before passing the data to Highcharts :

```
data: [{
    x: 1,
    open: 9,
    high: 2,
    low: 4,
    close: 6,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00"
}, {
    x: 1,
    open: 1,
    high: 4,
    low: 7,
    close: 7,
    name: "Point1",
    color: "#FF00FF"
}]
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.data

Answer (score 0):

It can be simply done using load event callback and updating points that pass the condition. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
  chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () {
        var chart = this,
            period = chart.series[1].options.params.period,
          mainSeries = chart.series[0],
          index,
          K,
          D;

        chart.series[1].processedYData.forEach(function (data, i) {
          K = data[0];
          D = data[1];

          if (K < D && K < 80) {
            index = i + period - 1;

            mainSeries.points[index].update({
                color: 'red'
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0k1gy49n/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update